# Get a percentage range of a list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, numpy

I'm trying to find the data range of a given percentage in a list. I want my result to be the highest and lowest extremes of that range. This is the simplest workable solution I have so far. 'The string formatting is just for testing, when I implement this it will only return the desired values'. If you don't understand what I am trying to achieve then run my code and you should be able to understand what I am trying to accomplish.

```
#Sample Data List
data = [
    4.252, 5.878, 1.435, -0.112, 6.97, -1.812, 0.887, 1.724, -1.452, 5.193,
    -1.001, 11.085, 1.335, 11.763, -7.284, -1.733, 3.175, 3.077, 0.249, -2.095,
    -0.253, 11.095, 5.184, 1.45, -3.882, 8.251, -4.234, -0.096, 5.957, -4.473,
    -3.874, 3.246, -0.929, -1.707, 2.079, 0.647, -8.189, 2.074, 3.226, 0.123,
    -3.097, -5.706, 4.276, 7.377, -5.861, 0.357, 0.966, -0.63, 2.129, 1.514,
    6.82, -1.854, 8.394, 5.141, -4.501, 1.307, -2.812, -0.348, 2.729, 2.232,
    4.096, -2.257, -4.802, -1.116, 1.346, 4.733, -1.391, -2.986, 2.8, 4.949,
    -4.101, 2.727, -1.267, -15.034, 5.322, 7.011, 6.36, 0.16, 0.719, 4.302,
    1.365, 3.098, -2.892, -4.589, -5.516, 2.182, -6.019, -6.75, 15.499, -4.58,
    3.516, 1.18, 9.648, -1.21, -10.911, -0.583, -0.545, 3.286, 0.51, 9.578,
    -2.444, 2.771, -3.846, -3.819, 1.877, 1.392, -2.784, -5.907, 4.206, 1.42,
    -2.279, -0.358, -0.649, 2.052, 1.04, 1.764, -3.156, -2.685, 0.106, 3.569,
    0.944, 3.797, -0.76, 4.89, -3.014, -2.118, -1.142, -1.578, -8.84, 3.034,
    -2.693, -2.989, -0.815, -2.504, 3.147, 1.596, -2.94, 0.906, -0.154, -3.765
     ]

#Input for percent range
percent = 50

#Get half of percentage
halfPercent = int(int((len(data) * float('.'+str(percent))/2)))

#Build string for printing later and create a counter
string = str(percent)+'% of data entries are beween values '
counter = 0

#Sort data and iterate up until it get to the counter gets to the halfPercent
for item in sorted(data):
    if item >= 0:
        counter += 1
        if counter >= halfPercent:
            string += str(item)
            counter = 0
            break
string += ' and '

#Sort data and iterate up until it get to the counter gets to the halfPercent
for item in sorted(data, reverse=True):
    if item <= 0:
        counter += 1
        if counter >= halfPercent:
            string += str(item)
            break

#Do the printing
print 'Min is ' + str(min(data)) + ' and Max is ' + str(max(data))
print string
```

This seems like it is not very pythonic and its a lot of code for the little it is doing. What better and more efficient methods are there?

Edit and Update...
Using and changing slightly the answer code that @DMfll posted helped a lot. Here is my new code.

```
#Sample data
data = [
    4.252, 5.878, 1.435, -0.112, 6.97, -1.812, 0.887, 1.724, -1.452, 5.193,
    -1.001, 11.085, 1.335, 11.763, -7.284, -1.733, 3.175, 3.077, 0.249, -2.095,
    -0.253, 11.095, 5.184, 1.45, -3.882, 8.251, -4.234, -0.096, 5.957, -4.473,
    -3.874, 3.246, -0.929, -1.707, 2.079, 0.647, -8.189, 2.074, 3.226, 0.123,
    -3.097, -5.706, 4.276, 7.377, -5.861, 0.357, 0.966, -0.63, 2.129, 1.514,
    6.82, -1.854, 8.394, 5.141, -4.501, 1.307, -2.812, -0.348, 2.729, 2.232,
    4.096, -2.257, -4.802, -1.116, 1.346, 4.733, -1.391, -2.986, 2.8, 4.949,
    -4.101, 2.727, -1.267, -15.034, 5.322, 7.011, 6.36, 0.16, 0.719, 4.302,
    1.365, 3.098, -2.892, -4.589, -5.516, 2.182, -6.019, -6.75, 15.499, -4.58,
    3.516, 1.18, 9.648, -1.21, -10.911, -0.583, -0.545, 3.286, 0.51, 9.578,
    -2.444, 2.771, -3.846, -3.819, 1.877, 1.392, -2.784, -5.907, 4.206, 1.42,
    -2.279, -0.358, -0.649, 2.052, 1.04, 1.764, -3.156, -2.685, 0.106, 3.569,
    0.944, 3.797, -0.76, 4.89, -3.014, -2.118, -1.142, -1.578, -8.84, 3.034,
    -2.693, -2.989, -0.815, -2.504, 3.147, 1.596, -2.94, 0.906, -0.154, -3.765
]

#Percent value needs to be variable
percent = 90

#Sorting and finding the percentage of data
half_way = int(len(data)*(float(""".{}""".format(percent))/2))

#Dictionary that will be returned from function later
returnDict = {
    'max' :  max(data),
    'min' : min(data),
    'high' : max([item for item in sorted(data) if item >= 0][0:half_way]),
    'low' : min([item for item in reversed(sorted(data)) if item <= 0][0:half_way])
}
#Print simply to view data
print """Max is {}, Min is {} and {}% of data entries are between values {} and {}""".format(returnDict['max'],
                                                                                             returnDict['min'],
                                                                                             percent,
                                                                                             returnDict['low'],
                                                                                             returnDict['high'])
```

Output looks like this.

```
Max is 15.499, Min is -15.034 and 90% of data entries are between values -8.84 and 6.36
```

Am still wondering if it can be done with less code. Maybe with numpy or another library?

Comment: What does "find the data range of a given percentage in a list" exactly mean? Can you give an example?

Comment: Please don't have variable names as `list`, that just shadows the built in function `list`.

Comment: This is just an example of what I am trying to achieve. When I implement this that value with be a list data-set from a database. I edited my post to change list to data.

Comment: @ReblochonMasque If you just run the code the output should explain your question.

Comment: Do it [the numpy way](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/routines.math.html)

Comment: @BoltzmannBrain could you give an example?

Comment: `data_array = np.array(data)` and then use the awesome vectorized numpy functions to do what you want. For example I think you'll make good use of [argsort](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output for this code is the same as the output of the code in the question.

```
data = [
4.252, 5.878, 1.435, -0.112, 6.97, -1.812, 0.887, 1.724, -1.452, 5.193,
-1.001, 11.085, 1.335, 11.763, -7.284, -1.733, 3.175, 3.077, 0.249, -2.095,
-0.253, 11.095, 5.184, 1.45, -3.882, 8.251, -4.234, -0.096, 5.957, -4.473,
-3.874, 3.246, -0.929, -1.707, 2.079, 0.647, -8.189, 2.074, 3.226, 0.123,
-3.097, -5.706, 4.276, 7.377, -5.861, 0.357, 0.966, -0.63, 2.129, 1.514,
6.82, -1.854, 8.394, 5.141, -4.501, 1.307, -2.812, -0.348, 2.729, 2.232,
4.096, -2.257, -4.802, -1.116, 1.346, 4.733, -1.391, -2.986, 2.8, 4.949,
-4.101, 2.727, -1.267, -15.034, 5.322, 7.011, 6.36, 0.16, 0.719, 4.302,
1.365, 3.098, -2.892, -4.589, -5.516, 2.182, -6.019, -6.75, 15.499, -4.58,
3.516, 1.18, 9.648, -1.21, -10.911, -0.583, -0.545, 3.286, 0.51, 9.578,
-2.444, 2.771, -3.846, -3.819, 1.877, 1.392, -2.784, -5.907, 4.206, 1.42,
-2.279, -0.358, -0.649, 2.052, 1.04, 1.764, -3.156, -2.685, 0.106, 3.569,
0.944, 3.797, -0.76, 4.89, -3.014, -2.118, -1.142, -1.578, -8.84, 3.034,
-2.693, -2.989, -0.815, -2.504, 3.147, 1.596, -2.94, 0.906, -0.154, -3.765]

half_way = len(data) // 4  # // division returns an int
sorted_data = sorted(data)

print("""Min is {} and Max is {}
50% of data entries are between values {} and {}""".format(
    max(sorted_data),
    min(sorted_data),
    max([item for item in sorted_data if item >= 0][0:half_way]),
    min([item for item in reversed(sorted_data) if item <= 0][0:half_way]),
))  # an alternate way of reversing an array is sorted_data[::-1]
```

It is best practice to not use variable names that are Python built-ins.

I changed `list` to `data`. `list` is a built-in in Python for creating lists, e.g. `list(range(10))`.

Comment: Satisfying result with a lot less code. I wish numpy or some other python library had something like this. I could be used a lot when dealing with financial markets. Take note that my percent was a variable so it could be dynamically changed later.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it satisfies your requirements.